# HQL, SQL - Get whole object (Get distance)

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have the following Query and I got a List with the datatype Double.
In this query I have as parameter the Longitude and the Latitude from a specific Location and also the distance.
With the "distance" paramater I can select the range between the different locations.

My issue is now, I would like to get a whole "City" - objects in my result List and not only a list from the differenct distance (double).
How should I modify that I got a list from my Entity "City" and not only Floats?

```
    public List<Double> findCityAroundSelectedCity(double longitude, double latitude, float distance) {

    String queryString = "SELECT (6371 * acos (cos(radians(" + latitude
            + ")) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians(" + longitude + "))  + sin(radians("
            + latitude + ")) * sin(radians(latitude)))) AS distance FROM City c HAVING distance < " + distance
            + " ORDER BY distance";

    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryString);

    List<Double> list = null;
    list = query.getResultList();

    return list;
}
```

Thank you very much for all help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `SELECT *` in the query, and specify your entity as the second parameter of the method  `createNativeQuery()`...

Try a `SQL` query, similar to this:

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT *, ( 6371 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( :lat ) ) * COS( RADIANS( latitude ) ) *
                   COS( RADIANS( longitude ) - RADIANS( :lng ) ) + SIN( RADIANS( :lat ) ) *
                   SIN( RADIANS( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance
       FROM City ) c
WHERE distance < :dis
ORDER BY distance
```

And the `Java` part:

```
public List<City> findCityAroundSelectedCity( double longitude, double latitude,
                                              float distance )
{
   // queryString should be a private static final, outside this method...
   return (List<City>) entityManager.createNativeQuery( queryString, City.class )
      .setParameter( "lat", latitude ).setParameter( "lng", longitude )
      .setParameter( "dis", distance ).getResultList();
}
```

BTW, this will return the source city as well, if it is in the table...

Comment: Add some unique id to the parameters, (both the method and the query,) and `id <> :id` to the `WHERE` clause...

Comment: You could "improve" this by using this unique id and the distance, and getting long/lat values from the table itself, by the id...

Comment: Got it..... SELECT * FROM ( SELECT *, ( 6371 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( :lat ) ) * COS( RADIANS( latitude ) ) * COS( RADIANS( longitude ) - RADIANS( :lng ) ) + SIN( RADIANS( :lat ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM City ) c WHERE distance < :dis AND (latitude <> :lat AND longitude <> :lng) ORDER BY distance";

Comment: One add. question: If I have distance = 50km but I would like to have only the cities which are really next to it (like TOP10).... How can I do this?